# How to read a text file and verify its context in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

My scenario is load test a functionality which will generate a text file at last, i need to verify the content of that file.
Please guide me step by step to achieve this functionality in jmeter from very beginning to last.

Answer (score 1):

Given you already have your file downloaded to your local hard drive:

1. Add [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to your Test Plan
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Protocol: `file`
   - Path: `/path/to/your/text/file.txt`
3. Add [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as a child of the HTTP Request
4. Configure it to test whether the file contains expected data.

See [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-extract-data-files-jmeter) for detailed instructions.

If the file lives in the web, take the same approach, but use `http` or `https` protocols to retrieve the file. To save it locally you can use [Save Responses to a File](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener